# Please suggest tools to test incoming e-mail functions

Tags: incoming-email

I would like to test the function that sending an email to Sharepoint server and Sharepoint will move the email document libarary.

From my understanding, Sharepoint will regularly check C:\inetpub\mailroot\Drop and move the mail file into library. So all I need to some tool to create those mail file in the Drop folder. Is there some handy tool to do so? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks a lot Robert. I will keep it as future reference.

In my test I need some email with attachment. So I do this way:

1. Setup smtp (with iis6) on localhost, map mydomain.com to it. Change the relay rule and authentication rule to allow everyone use (since it is just my test box)
2. Setup MX record @mydomain.com at DNS server:
   i.e. @mydomain.com --> localhost
3. Install a thin email client. (I used something really thin 2 years ago but I forgot the name so I use Thunderbird.) In the client set SMTP as localhost and no authentication required. We are ready to send email to local drop folder now.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently I was incorrectly remembering the process for working with this last night. So here is an update with more detail.

I have done this with just note pad. Usually I will take an email out of Outlook or other client and save it as a `.txt` file so that I can edit it easily. I'll make the adjustments to the `to`, `x-sender`, and `x-receiver` headers and then just save it to the folder as a `.eml`.

But really the best thing is to configure the environment so that when you send the email, it gets dropped in the folder as expected.

The most important thing is that you include

```
x-sender: user_lastname@domain.com
x-receiver: it_test_list@sharepoint.domain.com
```

Here is an example header you are welcome to use:

```
x-sender: user_lastname@domain.com
x-receiver: it_test_list@sharepoint.domain.com
Received: from US-XCH-01.domain.net ([10.1.1.7]) by usd-01.domain.net with Microsoft SMTPSVC(6.0.3790.4675);
     Tue, 15 Oct 2013 10:17:34 -0400
Received: from usd-04.domain.net ([10.1.1.44]) by US-XCH-01.domain.net with Microsoft SMTPSVC(6.0.3790.3959);
     Tue, 15 Oct 2013 10:18:24 -0400
Received: from USD-03.domain.net ([fe80::bd40:54db:3700:7e66]) by
 us-04.domain.net ([fe80::4c06:3001:d4ea:d2c4%12]) with mapi id
 14.02.0342.003; Tue, 15 Oct 2013 10:18:24 -0400
From: Robert Kaucher <user_lastname@domain.com>
To: "it_test_list@sharepoint.domain.com" <it_test_list@sharepoint.domain.com>
Subject:    A Third Test
Thread-Topic: a third test
Thread-Index: Ac7JsUXUHTketEOPTZ2a/Cbs1EHTVA==
Date: Tue, 15 Oct 2013 14:18:23 +0000
Message-ID: <4EBC97D98E660B46B9848C5A0D8414AB1CVC53D8@us-03.domain.net>
Accept-Language: en-US
Content-Language: en-US
X-MS-Has-Attach:
X-MS-TNEF-Correlator:
x-originating-ip: [10.1.1.216]
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
    boundary="_000_4EBC97D98E660B46B9848C5A0D8414AB1CAD53D8stuff_"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Return-Path: user_lastname@domaine.com
X-OriginalArrivalTime: 15 Oct 2013 14:18:24.0424 (UTC) FILETIME=[68C1AA80:01CEC9B1]

--_000_4EBC97D98E660B46B9848C5A0D8414AB1CAD53D8ustuff_
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="us-ascii"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

Body of message
```

Here is a screen shot showing it worked.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will keep it as future reference.

Because I need some email attachment so I do this:
1. Setup smtp (with iis6) on localhost